# C# DataTable chance columnmapping value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Step 1:

```
DataSet dsMain = new DataSet();
dsMain.ReadXml(my xml path);
```

Results I got 36 datatable in that `dsMain` dstaset.

Step 2:

Dynamically created 36 `DataGridView` to display all datatable.
It results some `DataGridView` has table but no data. And some columns were missing.
Reason those columns are auto generated Mapping column. And it column name like TabelName_Id.

Step 3:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ds1.Tables.Count; index++)
{
    DataTable dtnew = ds1.Tables[index].Copy();

    for (int ColCount = 0; ColCount < dtnew.Columns.Count; ColCount++)
    {
        if (dtnew.Columns[0].ColumnMapping == MappingType.Hidden)
        {
            dtnew.Columns[0].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that column is get visible. But my problem is I could not get parent auto generated column.

Example:

Tabel 1: Parent-> Columns(Parent_Id,Col1,Col2,Col3)

Tabel 2: Child -> Columns(Child_Id,Col1,Col2,Col3,Parent_Id)

after following step 3 I able to see Child_Id in Child table but I couldn't able to see Parent_Id in Child table.

Please help me get out of this.

My sample xml

```
<Parent value="25">
<Child>
<Inner></Inner>
</Child>
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop, your index is always 0. did you mean to use ColCount?

```
for (int ColCount = 0; ColCount < dtnew.Columns.Count; ColCount++)
{
   if (dtnew.Columns[ColCount].ColumnMapping == MappingType.Hidden)
   {
      dtnew.Columns[ColCount].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
   }
}
```

what does the above change do to your results? if you still see the parent/child issues, we can look further.